# Фильтрация базы данных через checkbox

Tags: android

Есть список заполняемый базой данных предметов с разными характеристиками, например:
Предмет1 - красный, овальный, большой
Предмет2 - красный, квадратный, большой
И так далее
Есть чекбоксы «красный» «большой»
Как сделать чтобы при выделении чекбокса «красный» в списке выводились предметы только с характеристиками «красный», при выделении «красный» и «большой», выводились только предметы с характеристиками красный и большой?

Comment: в таблице БД добавляете два столбца цвет и размер. делаете выборку по ним

Comment: Можно пример, хотябы приблизительный пожалуйста ?